# How do we use List Comprehension for the below code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

This was the given code and I want to use List Comprehension

```py
    import numpy as np
    
    linear_data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    
    plt.figure()
    xvals = range(len(linear_data))
    plt.bar(xvals, linear_data, width = 0.3)
    
    new_xvals = []
```

plot another set of bars, adjusting the new xvals to make up for the first set of bars plotted

```py
    for item in xvals:
        new_xvals.append(item+0.3)
    
    plt.bar(new_xvals, exponential_data, width = 0.3 ,color='red')
```

I wrote this line of code but I'm not getting the desired output

```py
    new_xvals = [items for items in xvals new_xvals.append(item+0.3)]
```

I was getting an error at `new_xvals.append(item+0.3)` when I used it after "xvals". How do I implement this?

Comment: `[item + 0.3 for item in xvals]`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the mistake you're making, I'm guessing you need the more explicit

```
    new_xvals = [i+0.3 for i in xvals]
```

The mistake you're making in your code is trying to append to the list in the interpolation.

Interpolation is creates the list all by itself, so all you need to do is assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The list can be constructed using the following list comprehension code:

```
[item+0.3 for item in xvals]
```